# Cannot declare a member of a Discriminated Union

Tags: generics, f#

The following code gives an compilation error about being "not sufficiently generic".
What is wrong?

```
type SameLenVectors<'T when 'T: (static member (+): 'T * 'T -> 'T) and 'T: (static member (*): 'T * 'T -> 'T)> =
    private SameLenVectors of 'T list list
        member this.Item = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'T` is a [statically resolved type parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters) (SRTP), so it must be inlined at the call site:

```ml
member inline this.Item = 1
```

It's a bit confusing, since you've declared the type parameter as `'T` rather than `^T`, but it's an SRTP nonetheless (as evidenced by the compiler error).